# How long should it take to conjure-up Openstack?

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

setup:

- ubuntu16.04 on vmware exsi 6.0 vm.
- following instruction to install openstack stack as given in http://conjure-up.io/.
- installed lxd as part of the process.
- installation process is now seems to hang after message regarding charms. It seems to endlessly running "pre-processing task":

[image]

What is the right behavior of this installation process? How long should I wait on deploy status?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Your post is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware I have 3rd generation Intel NUC with i7, 16G RAM, 250 SSD and a 300mbps connection. Picking the OpenStack with NovaLXD option so everything is deployed on a single system takes me about 30 minutes for a full deployment. This includes importing glance images, configuring keystone, configuring neutron and starting a compute instance to verify installation.